# magento api v2 boilerplate generator (creator)

Tags: soap-api-v2

Is there any online module creator / generator that can create the barebone files for extending magento api v2?

All I have so far is [Magento Module Creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) which only does api v1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an online tool, but I have a free magento module that can do that (among others).  [Ultimate Module Creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9).
It allows you to generate the files for API v1, API v2 (WS-I compliant and not), rest API files.
Explanations on how the files are created can be found in [the wiki](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki/entity-backend-settings)

Comment: thanks! i actually have your module and didn't notice it, will look in the wiki thanks again